# Make several cells of an HTML table appear joined without being so

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, cells

I have a table in html and I need to make several cells appear joined, without being actually joined. This because each cell must have a different background.

So I need to take away the right border from the left most cell;
take away the left border from the right most cells;
take away both border from the central cells.

Here is an example where I have a table with two rows, and 7 cells. In the second row, the cells should appear as being only 2 cells. One spanning 5 columns and one spanning 7.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
<td>foo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:white; border-right: blank; border-left: solid;"  >foo</td>
<td style="background-color:green; border-right: blank; border-left: blank;"  ></td>
<td style="background-color:black; border-right: blank; border-left: blank;"  ></td>
<td style="background-color:yellow; border-right: blank; border-left: blank;"  ></td>
<td style="background-color:blue; border-right: solid; border-left: blank;"  ></td>

<td style="background-color:red; border-right: blank; border-left: solid;"  >foo</td>
<td style="background-color:pink; border-right: solid; border-left: blank;"  ></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

But then this is still not enough because there is still some background of the table that is shown between the cells. How do I take of that?

Comment: could u please show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your table a class

```
<table class="myTable">
    <!-- Your Rows/Cells -->
</table>
```

Then with CSS do the following:

```
.myTable { 
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Also `border:blank` is incorrect, use `border:none` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed does what I needed, but now it looks ugly :-(. I did not need to take away the space between rows, nor the space in the rest of the table. Do I really need to force to take away the border for the whole table? Can I not just do it between the cells involved?

Comment: Absolutely not. You can add or remove the different lines in the CSS and see what they do. That will help you figure out what you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type='text/css'>
#left{
border-left:none;
}
#right{
border-right:none;
}
#both{
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
}
</style>
```

include these css ids in `<td>` elements of table.
example:
`<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>1111</td>
<td id='right'>2222</td>
<td id='both'>3333</td>
<td id='left'>4444</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: An id must be unique for the whole HTML document. Use CSS classes for this, not IDs.

Comment: Thanks. This leaves a bit of grey between the cells. How can I take that away?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td colspan="5" style="background-color:white; border-right: none; border-left: solid;">foo</td>
<td colspan="2"  style="background-color:red; border-right: solid; border-left: none;">foo</td>
```

### [Demo »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/shcG8/)

Comment: Thanks. This would not work, since the point is to have different background for each cell. While looking as if they are a single bigger cell.